# Are my centos venet0 settings causing url not to work on server?

Tags: node.js, centos, nameservers

I'm attempting to use node.js on centOS6 VPS to host a website.  I have a basic app running and everything works when I go to the ip 198.11.54.18, however when I go to the domain name sluap.com I get page not found.  I'm thinking something is wrong with my venet0 or venet0:0 configs, but I'm not sure what to look for.  I can ping sluap.com, and the whois stuff all looks correct, so I figure it has to be a setting or step in centOS that I'm doing wrong.  Maybe the problem is completely unrelated, any help would be appreciated, I've been trying to fix this for a long time.

ifconfig:
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr  00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  P-t-P:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:635 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1446 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:90742 (88.6 KiB)  TX bytes:163205 (159.3 KiB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:198.100.45.18  P-t-P:198.100.45.18  Bcast:198.100.45.18  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1

venet0 settings:
DEVICE=venet0
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
ARPCHECK="no"
IPADDR=127.0.0.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
BROADCAST=0.0.0.0
ARPCHECK="no"

venet0:0 settings:
DEVICE=venet0:0
ONBOOT=yes
ARPCHECK="no"
IPADDR=198.100.45.18
NETMASK=255.255.255.255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was using a2 hosting I was under the impression that my name server was NS1.A2HOSTING.COM, but for their vps they use dns1.name-services.com instead. Apparently the problem had 0% to do with the loop back config or the venet0 configurations.  They were all correct and working fine with a default centOS install...